# Special characters in Hasura GraphSQL queries

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have been using Hasura and Next.js to render html in the front-end (SSR). I have postures database and been using GraphQL queries through useQuery hook to get data.

My simple query will be like this:

```
query News_60($str) {
    news: news_aggregate(where: where: { text:{_ilike:$str}) {
      aggregate {
        count
      }
    }
  }
```

Above one gives me the count of news matching str. Example for str will be "%game%" (user types "game" in the search box). It works perfectly. It gives the news having "game" as part of text field. And If I pass "%game%of%" (user types "game of" in the search box). I am getting the results with "game" and "of" in it. Example: The game of thrones. That's perfectly fine with me. Now, the problem is When user types "game-type" in the search box.

I want Hasura to pick results with text having "game#type" or "game_type" or "game type". So, it should pick all the results having "game" and "type" words with any special characters or space in between. I tried "%game%type%". But it picking text containing any letters in between, but, I only want special characters in between.

Is there any special character handling in Hasura?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve that using **_similar** operator and SQL standard's regular expression.

```
{
  "str": "%game( |#|\\_)type%"
}
```

this matches any of the **space** or **#** or **_** character between two words!

One caveat might be case-sensitivity. one way to overcome this would be changing your column to a citext type

Comment: Aha. I will try this.

Comment: No problem! baba